# Solving a PDF infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Hi I am trying to solve an infinite series such that I can plot it in MATLAB.

The expression is

\begin{equation}
\label{sampler_equ}
PDF(\tau) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma ^2}}exp\biggl(-\frac{(\tau+kT-t_{\mu ,i})^2}{2\sigma ^2}     \biggl)
\end{equation}

I would like to express the PDF in a form so I can plot it. Could anyone assist on how I should approach this expression? I have not dealt with infinite sums in a while.

EDIT: Below is the expression that it can be approximated to. This is what the paper I am reading has stated. I am able to plot the expression below for various values of $A$. I can see the distribution is uniform when $A$ is small. The authors do not really describe how A is obtained. They only mention that it is a function of the $\sigma$ and $T$.

\begin{equation}
\label{sampler_equ2}
PDF(\tau) = \frac{1}{T_{CLK}}+Acos\biggl(2\pi \frac{\tau -t_{\mu ,i}}{T_{CLK}}\biggl).
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you sure it converges?  For each k it looks like a Gaussian  density.

Comment: Apparently it is supposed to converge to a uniform distribution. I am reading it from a IEEE paper so I am not sure I can actually share it or not.

Comment: This sum is not going to get any shorter.

Comment: It could convert to a uniform distribution if the domain of $\tau$ is finite.   The integral over all $\tau$ has to be = 1.

Comment: I added an edit to my question. If you see above the expression from the authors approximates a uniform distribution.